# How can I use Windows commands to check if apscheduler has been started?

Tags: python, apscheduler

I have some apscheduler processes , and I want to use Windows command to check if these processes are alive .

In Linux , I can use `ps -ef |grep "scrip name"` to find running script , but I want to find running python process in windows .

How can I do that ?

apscheduler example:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

def tick():
    print('Tick! The time is: %s' % datetime.now())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(tick, 'interval', seconds=3)
    scheduler.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  **sc.exe**

Type in cmd:

> for /f "tokens=2*" %a in ('sc query serviceName ^| findstr STATE') do echo %b

Replace '*serviceName*' with apscheduler

Comment: I can't get anything , if I run python with command `python worker.py` , and use this command `for /f "tokens=2*" %a in ('sc query worker ^| findstr STATE') do echo %b` @MrV

Comment: Try replacing percentage sign with double percentage signs

Comment: And worker is not your service name, it is your source code filename.

Comment: I 'm not add process to windows service , I just run in command , so I thing sc.exe is used to check windows service , right ?

Answer (score 0):

I find the way to check if the process have been started using Windows command.

```
wmic process where "name='python.exe'" get commandline,processid | find "MyPythonFilename"
```